# I want to get pairs of first and second letters of strings with the same length (by using LINQ)

Tags: c#, string, list, linq

I have 2 lists of strings

```cs
List<string> A = new List<string> { "1QWERTY", "ASDF4B2J", "C0QW", "8D" };
List<string> B = new List<string> { "GJ65SJ2", "KO21L94B", "ABF287KF2", "GPK25" };
```

And I want to get pairs of first and second letters of strings with the same length (by using LINQ).

Like `1Q: GJ` or `AS: KO`.

So, I wrote this code:

```cs
var res = A.Join(
  B,
  a => a.Length,
  b => b.Length,
  (a, b) => new { str = a[0] + a[1] + ": " + b[0] + b[1] }
);

foreach (var e in res)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.str);
}
```

But instead of `1Q` or `AS` using `a[0]` and `a[1]` I got some numbers.
So, result of this request is:

```
130: GJ
148: KO
```

But when I use only `a[0]` or `a[1]`:

```cs
var res = A.Join(B, a => a.Length, b => b.Length, (a, b) => new { str = a[0] + ": " + b[0] + b[1] });
```

I got a correct symbol, like:

```
1: GJ
A: KO
```

So, why does It works like that and how should I change my code to make it work correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is nothing to do with linq.

`a[0]` is a `char`, not a `string`. Perhaps confusingly, there's no addition operator defined for `char`: you can't add two `chars` together to get a `string`.

*However*, a `char` is implicitly convertible to the integral types, and there's an addition operator for `ints`. So if you do `'A' + 'B'`, that gets converted to `65 + 66`, which is the integer `131`.

Then we try and add this to a `string`. There is an addition operator defined between anything and a `string`, which works by calling `ToString()` on the thing that isn't a string, and then concatenating it with the string. So `131 + ": "` is the same as `131.ToString() + ": "`, which is the string `"131: "`.

When we come to add on `b[0]` and `b[1]`, we do this by adding first doing `"131: " + b[0]`. This follows the same rules about string addition as above, so gets turned into `"131: " + b[0].ToString()`, which is e.g. `"131: " + 'C'.ToString()`, which is "131: C". Then we do the same when adding on `b[1]`.

There are several ways to do what you want: you can do `a[0].ToString() + a[1] + ": " + ...` to force that first `char` to turn into a `string`. Or you can do `"" + a[0] + ...` to achieve the same thing. The easiest thing, though, is not to use string concatenation at all, and instead do `$"{a[0]}{a[1]}: {b[0]}{b[1]}"`.

Another way is to not pick out individual chars, but instead of `a.Substring(0, 2)` to pull out the first two chars as a string. Then you can write either `a.Substring(0, 2) + ": " + b.Substring(0, 2)`, or $"{a.Substring(0, 2)}: {b.Substring(0, 2)}"`.

Note that none of this is safe if you've got any strings which are 0 or 1 characters long!

Comment: Because you added `": "` just before. So, you are adding`b[0]` and `b[1]` to a string, not to another char.

Comment: Thanks, i add " " before a[0] and it works now, but how should I change my code to make it more universal without adding " "?

Comment: @Roomey Use interpolation or `string.Format`.

Comment: I would use `string.Format` for this kind of thing, and not bother with the `+` signs.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.append?view=netframework-4.8), which has an Append method overload that accepts individual characters.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply update the result selector `Func` in [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Join__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1___2__System_Func___0___1___3__) method to

```cs
(a, b) => new { str = $"{a.Substring(0,2)}:{b.Substring(0,2)}" }
```

This will get first two letters from `a` and `b` strings and concatenate them into one string using [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated). Output will be the following

```
1Q:GJ
AS:KO
```

Answer (score 0):

In your solution instead of using string index use string Substring as follows

```
var res = A.Join(B,
              a => a.Length,
              b => b.Length,
              (a, b) => new { str = a.Substring(0,2) + ":" + b.Substring(0,2) });
```